# Xquery to find all words in italic <i>

Tags: xml, xquery

I am trying to write an XQuery that will return a list of all words in italics () for an xml like:

```
<p>There is abundant evidence of a widened and deepened interest in <i>modern</i>
 science. How could it be <i>otherwise</i> when we <i>think</i> of the magnitude and the
 eventfulness of recent advances?</p>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let $p := 
<p>There is abundant evidence of a widened and deepened interest in 
<i>modern</i> science. How could it be <i>otherwise</i> when we <i>think</i> of the
magnitude and the eventfulness of recent advances?</p>
return $p/i
```

If you will have italics nested within elements, you can search all descendants using `$p//i`. If you want a sequence of strings instead of `<i>` elements, you can use:

```
for $i in $p/i
return string($i)
```

Or some XQuery processors will support the more concise `$p/i/string()`.

Comment: mm.. well but if I have to load from a document? something like: let $p:= doc("/documents/chapter_02.xml") //libro
return $p/i

Comment: If a processor doesn't support $p/i/string(), then it's not an XQuery processor. And I would use $p//i/string() since the markup almost certainly allows rendition tags to be nested.

Comment: @MichaelKay Okay, thanks. Maybe I was thinking thinking XPath 1 vs 2?